# Why is Random.nextInt() %16 skewed while Random.nextInt(16) works perfectly fine?

Tags: java, random, casting, bukkit, modulo

I am writing a Bukkit plugin that treats snowballs as paintballs. When I accidentally used:

```
(byte) (random.nextInt() % 16)
```

instead of

```
(byte) (random.nextInt(16))
```

I noticed that lower numbers appeared way more than higher numbers. Why does that happen?

Ex: Before:

```
00010
01200
06001
30010
00502
```

Ex: After:

```
74108
73447
98956
17386
26574
```

Comment: It's not at all clear how your code relates to your output. Can you provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: What research have you done? Did you create a histogram to see how the distribution happens? Did that correspond to your expectations? What hypothesis did you form to explain the behaviour? Do you think the byte cast might be relevant? Stack Overflow should be a last resort, not just a "hey that's curious -- let's ask them".

Comment: The numbers you show could not come from either expression, as those return integers in the range 0-15.

Comment: @JimGarrison It was an example of 0-9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`random.nextInt()` can also return negative values, and my program was treating negatives as zero, <strike>doubling</strike> tripling the chance for a zero to occur.

Comment: Nice catch! And yeah, the `%` operator can trick people - it doesn't mean "Modulo", which a lot of people think it does, it means "Remainder". The difference is that Remainder can be negative, while Modulo will always be positive.